# How to fix the tabs properly using css?

Tags: html, css, angular

Hi i am trying to integrate tabs in my project here css is fine but after clicking on the second tab it is not visible and also button click is not happening.

This is the code which i tried: [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-utc7gm?file=src/app/app.component.html)

Any answer would be helpful thanks.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Well for that ' rounded ' active background you are using `:after` pseudo element on the `ul`. Why would you do that ? you want to animate it ( move it from one active `li` to another ) ?

If you not, just add ' after ' or just add a background to the active element.

See [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-htymsg?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.css) and let me know if that's what you were looking for.

P.s. the tabs work so  i don't know what you mean about ' button click is not happening.'

Comment: Well this works fine but after clicking on the other tab it vanishes and reappears that shouldnt be happening any fix i got this solution before.

Comment: it' vanishes ' ? You mean it takes some time to change the color from blueish to white ? that's the effect of the transition applied on `tab-slider--trigger `

Comment: Yes i dont want that effect any solution for this.

Comment: :))) maybe delete the transition applied to `tab-slider--trigger` ? :)

Answer (score -1):

You wrong two css property i change it :

```
.tab-slider--trigger.active {
    color: #fff;
    background-color: #345F90; // add only when active
}
.tab-slider--trigger {
    background-color:white; // add when is not active white
}

.tab-slider--tabs:after {
    background: #345F90; // delete because is wrong
}
```

Complete css file:

```css
.container {
    width: 75%;
    margin: 3rem auto;
}

h2 {
    color: #345F90;
    font-size: 24px;
    line-height: 1.25;
    font-family: "Roboto Slab", serif;
    margin-top: 20px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.tab-slider--nav {
    width: 100%;
    float: left;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.tab-slider--tabs {
    display: block;
    float: left;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    list-style: none;
    position: relative;
    border-radius: 35px;
    overflow: hidden;
    background: #fff;
    height: 35px;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    -moz-user-select: none;
    -ms-user-select: none;
    user-select: none;
}

.tab-slider--tabs:after {
    content: "";
    width: 50%;
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    -webkit-transition: all 250ms ease-in-out;
    transition: all 250ms ease-in-out;
    border-radius: 35px;
}

.tab-slider--tabs.slide:after {
    left: 50%;
}

.tab-slider--trigger {
    font-size: 12px;
    line-height: 1;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #345F90;
    background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
    text-transform: uppercase;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 11px 20px;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 2;
    cursor: pointer;
    display: inline-block;
    -webkit-transition: color 250ms ease-in-out;
    transition: color 250ms ease-in-out;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    -moz-user-select: none;
    -ms-user-select: none;
    user-select: none;
}

.tab-slider--trigger.active {
    color: #fff;
    background-color: #345F90;
}

.tab-slider--body {
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}
```